# which one is the best: facebox, thickbox, jquery ui dialog, others?

Tags: jquery, lightbox, thickbox, facebox

which one is the best to use for:

1. images
2. regular div content
3. ajax loaded content
4. forms to post to server

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would recommend both [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) and jQuery UI Dialog, though UI Dialog will be weaker on displaying images. I personally think ColorBox handles images in nicer way considering Dialog was built to be, well, a dialog :).

**Update:** Apparently the ColorBox server is down for some reason. You'll have to take my word for it... haha. Hope its up soon. The code is also [available on Github](http://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox).

Comment: upvoting wasn't quite enough on this one. +1

Answer (score 1):

[Shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) is the cat's meow.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this sort of thing is mostly subjective; I've used lightbox and facebox in the past. They are both easy enough to use and look great.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Thickbox and  found it's easy to implement... It's versatile too... Images, Forms are well supported.... and yes. for ajax loaded content too..!

Jquery UI provids only some basic functionalities.. It's pretty good with forms and alerts.. but not that much suitable for images...

Comment: Thickbox isn't supported anymore.  It still works, but it's just not going to be advanced.  I've also had trouble with Thickbox and any JS in the thickbox to execute with Safari/Chrome (I think it's a webkit thing).  Example:  A thickbox with a form and there are tooltips on the form.  Tooltips work in every browser except Safari/Chrome.  Something to think about before moving on with Thickbox.